# Write a function that takes two arguments, x and n, and returns h(x, n). using FOR loop

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R that takes two arguments, x and n, and returns h(x, n); x=1
Does anyone know how to do this using a for loop?

The function I am working with is:
x^0 + x^1 + x^2...x^n

I have been working for a while on this and am not sure if I am doing this correctly.
Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do this problem.

Here is what I have..

```
n = seq(1,6, by = 1)
x = 1
h = function (x,n){
    for (i in 0:n){
        for( i in 1:n){
        sum = sum +x^i
    {
}}
```

Comment: What happens when you try the code above?

Comment: A for loop is not the right way to do this.  Since R is vectorized: `sum(x^n)`. If its homework, then please label it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h <- function( x, n ) sum( x^c(0:n) ) 
h( 1, 6 )
```

1. Loops are best avoided in R. First, you can use vectors in many situations; then, learn to use `apply` and friends (`sapply`, `lapply` etc.).
2. Do yourself a favor and use `<-` instead of `=` in assignments. It pays off in the long run.
3. Like in other programming languages, no need to declare the variables *outside* of the function (and anyways, since n is an argument to your function, your first assignment has no effect on the function)
4. Don't use `seq()` where a simple `k:n` will do.